# Correct Present Perfect Usage: Is it Disappearing?

Tags: verbs, vocabulary

Certain verbs such as drink, speak, and swim seemed to be misused more and more with this tense. Is this a regional phenomenon or common in all English speaking countries?
For example, in southern Illinois and western Michigan many people say, I have spoke, I have swam, or I have drank and opposed to using spoken, swum or drunk.

Comment: Language, like everything else, inexorably and ineluctably changes. This is neither good nor bad, merely annoying: all change is amoral, so judgments about change are merely expressions of personal preference (_I like it_ versus _I dislike it_). Even the grammar of English is changing. "Misusing the language" has come to mean "not using the language the way I do, and it sounds strange, stupid, and ugly to me". Arguing and expressing opinions about this is politics, not linguistics: you can tell because of the zealousness with which language abusers defend themselves. (Oops!) (B-O

Comment: "If my speech ain't broke, don't fix it!". I get 18.8M hits on Google for [broke](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22if+it+ain't+broke+don't+fix+it%22&oq=%22if+it+ain't+broke+don't+fix+it%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.13394&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), but only 1.1M for [broken](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22if+it+ain't+broken+don't+fix+it%22&oq=%22if+it+ain't+broken+don't+fix+it%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.92584&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Yes, "correct" usage is disappearing (everywhere, not just among "uneducated" Illinoians).

Comment: This sounds like peeving, and I have voted to close for this reason.

Comment: There really is no way of answering this right now. I'm voting to close as well.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to your question of "Is it Disappearing?" is no.

I generated [Google ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/) for all three examples you gave "*have swum* vs. *have swam*", "*have spoken* vs. *have spoke*", and "*have drunk* vs. *have drank*", and I found that for all three usages, the usage frequency for the incorrect usages has remained stable and low for a long time, and for all three examples, the incorrect usage was in fact more common in the past, not less common.

**[*Have swam* vs. *have swum*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20swam/%28have%20swam%2bhave%20swum%29,have%20swum/%28have%20swam%2bhave%20swum%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)**
[image: have swam vs have swum]

**[*Have spoke* vs. *have spoken*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20spoke/%28have%20spoke%2bhave%20spoken%29,have%20spoken/%28have%20spoke%2bhave%20spoken%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)**
[image: Have spoke vs. have spoken]

**[*have drunk* vs. *have drank*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+drank%2F%28have+drank%2Bhave+drunk%29%2Chave+drunk%2F%28have+drank%2Bhave+drunk%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)**
[image: have drunk vs. have drank]

Your observations are probably just an example of the [recency illusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recency_illusion), the belief or impression that something is of recent origin when it is in fact long-established.

Comment: +1, because I'm sure this is right, but we must remember that nGrams tell us only about writing, not speech.

Comment: @BarrieEngland ... and the OP appears to be only aware of speech in parts of Illinois and Michigan :)

Comment: [This NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+ain%27t+broke%2Cit+ain%27t+broken&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) for *it ain't broke/broken* may be a special case, but it certainly shows a massive rise in the "non-grammatical" form over recent decades.